# How to read currently downloading file -Js OR Python

Tags: javascript, python

Let's say that I'm downloading a file and at the same time I want to read it but that the file content always get updated.
For example let's assuming that I start read the file when the progress bar was at 60% is there a way to read and wait at the same time for the remaining part which is the 40% of the file content that is currently downloading.

I tired the normal reading method in python:

```
with open('downloadingfile.mp4', 'rb') as f:
   data = f.read()
   # remaining code which is not important
```

Comment: You can call `f.read()` periodically in a loop, each call will return whatever has been added since the previous one. But unless you know the expected file size, there's no way to tell when you've gotten everything.

Comment: I was thinking of your method previously but if the file size was big and I have alot of files that is downloading isn't that harmful for Cpu and Rams? plz tell if you know another method, And yeah I have a method that gives me the file size

Comment: Call `time.sleep()` in the loop to avoid overloading.

Comment: @amjdalqasemy it wont b harmful for your CPU, but the RAM could get full. But this will happen independently of the method, because it makes no difference if you read 1 time 10 GB or 10 times 1 GB in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the expected file size, call `read()` in a loop until you get to that size.

```
import time

with open('downloadingfile.mp4', 'rb') as f:
    total_read = 0
    while total_read < file_size:
        data = f.read()
        if data:
            total_read += len(data)
            # process this chunk
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Barmar, I think you meant to ___add___ the length of `data` to `total_read`, instead of overwriting `total_read`-

Answer (score 0):

you must first know that there is an advanced way for threading and this way big companies use but here I am going to show a threading way but it is not advanced try this code I don't know if it is going to work I am new in programming

```
def Handel_Progress(self , blocknum , blocksize , totalsize):
    ## calculate the progress
    readed_data = blocknum * blocksize

    if totalsize > 0 :
        download_percentage = readed_data * 100 / totalsize
        self.setValue(download_percentage)
        processEvents()# before process even put the name of the application or if you are using python without make to it GUI I don't know what to do
```

Comment: Just for context : this seems to be taken from a Qt application.